# Is it possible to engineer water-walking boots?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, control-engineering

A naive question, yes, I know, but it's something that has plagued me for a long time. Whether by secreting a substance, controlled vibrations, metamaterials, or powered systems, is it possible to make something that would otherwise sink, not sink, preferably to an extent where (possibly with extra wide soles) boots may allow walking on water, even if only for a short period of time?

It's a hypothetical contemplation, so anything goes, including things that react explosively or otherwise violently with water, high-tech materials, experimental tech, etc.

Comment: Your title should be rephrased, it is not possible to increase the surface tension of water as it is defined as a basic property of a liquid. So the answer would be no.  But is it possible, from a scientific perspective, to walk on water? From a scientific and engineering perspective, that is another question entirely.  For instance, hovercraft can give the _appearance_ of _walking on water_.

Comment: There was a myth busters episode on this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GWhOLorDtw

Comment: Was this prompted by a timely viewing of BTTF Part II, I wonder?

Comment: I've read that real, historical ninjas put their feet in large pots to cross water and stay dry. They might have needed a pole to propel themselves though, and I'm sure that balancing would be difficult. I don't remember the specifics.

Answer (score 8):

There are some possibilities, but none of them sound practical.

First, let's take a look at ordinary displacement.  Let's say the boots need to hold up 200 pounds, so 200 pints of water need to be displaced, or 25 gallons.  That's 12.5 gallons per boot just to hold you up with both feet in the water.  It's 25 gallons per boot for "walking" where all the weight must be supported by a single foot regularly.  25 gallons is about 95 liters, which is the volume of a cube about 460 mm on a side.  No matter how you shape that volume, you're not going to be "walking" with something that big attached to your shoes, let alone somehow be able to balance and not fall over.

Given enough power, you can in theory pump water down to create enough reaction force to hold you up.  Again though, this won't leave you with anything like a "walking" motion to move forwards.  You've probably seen pictures of people hovering over water with a sort of "jet pack" that squirts water down at high volume and high speed.  These obviously work, but arranging that at your feet will be tricky.

The reason "walking" just won't work on water is that walking relies on friction with the ground to move laterally and to maintain balance.  Think how differently you walk just on ice, and that motion is still relying on the little friction between the bottoms of your shoes and the ice.  With water there will be no static friction at all, only viscous friction.  The human control system for walking just won't work with no static friction, and balancing will be very very difficult at best, given that the force holding you up is well below your center of mass, and you can't rely on the usual friction for sideways forces to dynamically correct for the inevitable imbalances.

There are a few more possible techniques I can think of for creating upwards force on special boots atop water, but these are pointless since anything like walking won't be possible.  With the right control system and steerable force, you could stay upright and propel yourself in the desired direction, but this is not "walking" by any reasonable interpretation.